# Having trouble coming up with a simple counter-example

Tags: linear-algebra

give a counterexample: If $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ is a basis of $V$ and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $v_1,v_2 \in U$ and $v_3, v_4 \notin U$, then $v_1, v_2$ is a basis of $U$.

Im having trouble coming up with a simple counter example.

Comment: Do you know what dimension $U$ needs to be?

Comment: It is not given, which i was confused by as well.

Answer (score 5):

Let $k$ be any field, $V = k^4$, $(v_i)$ be the standard basis and $U$ be the subspace spanned by $(1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but doesnt the problem ask for 4 vectors in v1,v2,v3,v4

Comment: Let $v_1 = (1, 0, 0, 0)$, $v_2 = (0, 1, 0, 0)$, $v_3 = (0, 0, 1, 0)$ and $v_4 = (0, 0, 0, 1)$. I've edited the original answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

To be a *basis*, the set need to be **linearly independent** and be able to **span the vector space**. Think it in this way, since U is a *subspace* of V, so U could be 3-dimension, but v1 and v2 can't span a 3D space so you can come up with a counterexample.